# How to process html user input Django?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, search

I want to process html form user input using Django. This I can do with Django form method but I want to do this with html form .

In short I want to take user input from html search box and in back-end Django will give related information from LDAP. LDAP part I have done but getting user input and passing values to LDAP search is making problem for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data you are looking for is inside the `request.POST`, you can access your field's value like this:

`request.POST.get('YOUR_FIELD', None)`

In case you are using the GET method, use the following:

`request.GET.get('YOUR_FIELD')`

Comment: Thanks and is there need to save user input in database. As when I tried to call html_category name then it says "Category_name" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your function to process html arguments should be like this.

```
def DoSomething():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            category_name = request.POST.get("categoryname")
            .
            .
    if request.method == 'GET':
            .
            .
```

[Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/) to django docs.

Comment: Thanks and is there need to save user input in database. As when I tried to call html_category name then it says "Category_name" is not defined.

Comment: I recommend you check out the django tutorial. Its good and will answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks...It worked

Comment: Mark the answer as correct then.